# how to run docker exec on a docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a mysql database schema during the docker-compose.yml file is getting executed

```
  version: "2"
  services:
  web:
    build: docker
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

   mysql:
   image: mysql:latest
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=test

     ports:
      - "3306:3306"
   links:
    - web

 onrun:
 command: "docker exec -i test_mysql_1 mysql -uroot -proot test <dummy1.sql"
```

I tried onrun but this is not working .
i am building the first image but pulling the second image from the docker hub.
kindly help in how to execute the following command after the docker-compose up

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is nothing like `onrun` in `docker-compose`. It will only bring up the containers and execute the command. Now you have few possible options

**Use mysql Image Initialization**

```
mysql:
 image: mysql:latest
 environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
  volumes: 
    - ./dummy1.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dummy1.sql
 ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

You may your sql files inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` inside the container

**Use bash script**

```
docker-compose up -d
# Give some time for mysql to get up
sleep 20
docker-compose exec mysql mysql -uroot -proot test <dummy1.sql
```

**Use another docker service to initialize the DB**

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: docker
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

   mysql:
   image: mysql:latest
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=test

     ports:
      - "3306:3306"
   mysqlinit:
     image: mysql:latest
     volumes:
       - ./dummy1.sql:/dump/dummy1.sql
     command: bash -c "sleep 20 && mysql -h mysql -uroot -proot test < /dump/dummy1.sql"
```

You run another service which will init the DB for you, like `mysqlinit` in the above one

Answer (score 8):

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order.

From https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

That is the convenient way how many databases (postgresql, mysql, ...) are initializing themselves on container-creation. You should create a *.sql / *.sh file and bind it via *volume* into the new container:

```
db:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes: 
    - ./db/entrypoint:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=iamgroot
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=gotg
```

This loads all your sql / sh files into the container which are then automatically executed.

Comment: They only get automatically executed if the data folder is empty